# How to get text from XML via Python?

Tags: python, xml, data-processing, txt, language-model

I'm training language model. My input are subtitles in XML format. I need to get just plain text from it and save to to a text file so I can work with it.

### Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <document> <s id="1"> <time id="T1S" value="00:00:14,660" /> <w id="1.1">-</w> <w id="1.2">Všetko</w> <w id="1.3">v</w> <w id="1.4">poriadku</w> <w id="1.5">.</w> </s></document>
```

### Output

```
- Všetko v poriadku .
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of the data you have and what you want to extract from it?

Comment: You really need to describe in detail what you want to do. `xml` is a text-based format anyway, so it is ambiguous what you want to do.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga et. al: He said he's training a language model, therefore he's interested in text without markup. He can easily obtain the string value of any element or even the document root using lxml and XPath as I show [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65509763/290085).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XML terms, you want the *string-value* of the XML element of interest.

Here is how to get the string-value of the root element in Python using XPath:

```
import lxml.etree as ET


xmlstr = """
  <r status="ready">
    <line>First line.</line>
    <line>Second line, with <i>italic text</i>.</line>
  </r>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
svalue = root.xpath('string(/)')
print(svalue)
```

The above code prints only the text,

```
    First line.
    Second line, with italic text.
```

as requested